# SQL data in azure datalake gen2

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2

I read that azure datalake gen 2 can store both structured and unstructured data. Where can we store structure data like SQL data in azure datalake gen2 .If I store it in blob, what will be the extension of that file. Is it .bak.
Basically any examples of storing SQL data in datalake please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the `structured data` you mean is `relational data` like sql data, the Azure data lake gen2(and also the azure blob storage) does not support it.

You can only store these data like in text format. And you can use Azure Data Factory to do that. Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal) for more details. Note: In this article, the sql data is exported to azure blob storage, you can easily use Azure data lake storage gen2 to replace blob storage.

And if you want to backup the sql database, then you can follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=SSMS), and at this time, the extension is .bak.